# Import error in python2.7 in ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, importerror

Whenever I run any python2 program or open python interpreter I get the following error.

```
$~/python> python setup.py
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

If I fire the following command

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I have also tried reinstalling the python using following command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

but it dosent help at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local. Python should be installed in /usr/local on OS X.

Comment: your last line is a bit off-topic. user is getting an error in ubuntu and you are suggesting something on OS X

Comment: I fixed the error. I fired the following command instead `$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7' . /usr/local/lib/python2.7 is the address of python virtual environment. But the _error reappears_ as soon as I restart my ubuntu. How can I permanently fix the error and how to set PYTHOPATH for python3.  @Gahan @praneet drolia

Comment: try to setup python with anaconda

Comment: alias python=/usr/bin/python3  ..........................
Write this command in your ~/.bash_aliases file........................
sudo nano ~/.bash_aliases............... This will automatically set python path to python 3 when u open ur terminal